# Publishing React Native App on Google Play with Expo on Linux

Tags: android, react-native

I've created a simple app in React Native, and I'd like to build it for potential publication on Google Play. How can I do that? I've gone through a few guides, but usually, I get to a point where I need to perform certain actions in the "android" directory, which I don't have in my project directory. I'm still fairly new to React Native. I'm using Expo, and I've been running the app through Expo on my phone, and I've been developing the app on Linux.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Expo to manage your app, you can use EAS to build your app and publish it to the Play Store.

This link has everything you need to do: https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

Comment: The answer could do with some more information. I.E. what is EAS and why should the asker use EAS?
Whilst it is encouraged to post links to external resources, it could do with some more information, like; quoting some relevant information from the docs in case the webpage goes offline or moves. 
This answer would improve significantly if you did not have to click the link in order to understand.